# Javascript: Window open and close.How to declare a window into a variable and pass to another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, window

I create two button, 
Open Button is Open the Child window.
Close Button is to close the Child Window.
Both button located at the parent window.

Here is the sample code

```
$("#to-open").click(function () { 
    var popUp = window.open( _contextPath + "open.jsp","Child", "width=500, height=300").focus();
});

$("#to-close").click(function () { 
        // No sure how to get the popUp object
     //popUp.close();
    });
```

Now I having difficulty on close window. 
I cannot pass the var popUp to the closing window function. 
Any advice or clue?

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply declare the popUp variable in outer scope:

```
var popUp;
$("#to-open").click(function () { 
    popUp = window.open( _contextPath + "open.jsp","Child", "width=500, height=300").focus();
});

$("#to-close").click(function () { 
    if (popUp)
        popUp.close();
});
```

Comment: I alter your code by remove the if(popUp).
The Firebug complain that 
"TypeError: popUp is undefined
popUp.close();"

Any clue?

Comment: Solved:
.focus() cause it.

I put it into a new line.
popUp.focus in open Button.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to put your window object in the global object.

```
var popUp;
$("#to-open").click(function () { 
    window.popUp = window.open( _contextPath + "open.jsp","Child", "width=500, height=300").focus();
});
```

This gets ugly though and it is considered best practice to not clutter up your global.

What would be cleaner is something like this

```
<button id="to-open">
</button>
<button id="to-close">
</button>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var popUp = 0;

    $("#to-open").click(function () { 
        popUp++;
    });

    $("#to-close").click(function () { 
        alert(popUp);
    });                 
});
```